# symbol barcode pdf417 EMDK

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, motorola-emdk

I'm developing an application using the EMDK v2.4 from Symbol. I'm trying to read a PDF417 barcode using the camera imager on the MC75. It is returning a readerData.Length of 234 characters but only the first 20 are readable via the readerData.Text property. When I use dataWedge, the PDF417 is decoded and shown properly. In dataWedge, using notes to view the result, it takes 3-4 seconds to decode the entire barcode. When I view the read_notify event in my test app, it is getting called in less than 1 second from when the scan completes. I assume this is why the barcode text is only the first 20 characters? Does anyone have any insight on how I can set the either set the device to not call read_notify until the decoding has completed, or offer advice on how I can get all of the decoded text.

Thank you!

Comment: You should show us the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to enable the Type of barcodes your app needs to read. For instance Code 128, EAN-8, EAN-13. In addition to this you have to indicate the min and max size of the expected barcode lenght. e.g. min= 8 characters and max= 12 therefore the scanner will try to decode within that range. 
Now, the more barcode types you enable, the more combination of decodes are tested while decoding. So consider enabling only the types you need, this will speed up the decoding process.
Also try to limit as much as you can the range of the barcode. so if you know that for code x the possible barcodes only can have from 10 to 12 characters, then set this limitation on the scanner configuration. instead of having it from 6 to 13.

By the way, the current EMDK for .NET is v2.7